# opencv java Error loading class org/bytedeco/javacpp/Loader. snapshot from video

Tags: java, image, maven, spring-mvc, opencv

i am trying to generate a snapshot from a video using the following code. and it is working fine running as a java application on sts.

```
public class VideoThumbTaker {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("/home/anupam/Downloads/jk.mp4");
        g.setFormat("mp4");
        try {
            g.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++) {
            try {
                ImageIO.write(g.grab().getBufferedImage(), "png", new File("/home/anupam/Downloads/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

         try {
            g.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

using maven dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

after deploying  a war file.the following code gives Error loading class org/bytedeco/javacpp/Loader

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "menu9data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
                public JSONObject view(@RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile image,@Valid MenuData model, BindingResult results)  {
        String name1;
          FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("/home/anupam/Downloads/"+name1);  //Error
                                    g.setFormat("mp4");
                                    try {
                                        System.out.println("enterss");
                                        g.start();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++) {
                                      /*  try {
                                        //  ImageIO.write(((Object) g.grab()).getBufferedImage(), "png", new File("/home/anupam/Downloads/"+name1+"snap"));
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }*/
                                    }
                                     try {
                                        g.stop();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
        }
}
```